# consuming a php webservice in Xamarin PCL

Tags: php, web-services, xamarin.forms

I have the following webservice in php

```
function w_getLesVisites($idVisiteur)
{
    return json_encode($pdo->getLesVisiteur($idVisiteur));
}
```

In my Xamarin form PCL project I have the following RestService class that aims to consume the phpwebservice and retrieve the data from my MySQL local database

```
public class RestService
    {
        HttpClient client;
        public List<Visite> L_Visites { get; private set; }

        public RestService()
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
            client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 25600;
        }

        public async Task<List<Visite>> RefreshDataAsync()
        {


            string restUrl = "localhost/ppe3JoJuAd/gsbAppliFraisV2/w_visite";
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(restUrl, string.Empty));

            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    L_Visites = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Visite>>(content);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            return L_Visites;
        }
    }
```

My question is: how can I call the php webservice with an id so that it returns a json value as expected ?

Comment: in a REST API, you would generally just append the ID onto your URL, like "/w_visite/7", but it may vary depend on how your service is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a single item from the webservice, simply create another method as below:

```
public async Task<Visite> GetSingleDataAsync(int id)
{
    //append the id to your url string
    string restUrl = "localhost/ppe3JoJuAd/gsbAppliFraisV2/w_visite/" + id;
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(restUrl, string.Empty));

    //create new instance of your Visite object
    var data = new Visite();

    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Visite>(content); //do not use list here
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    return data;
}
```

As suggested by @Jason, your url format may vary depend on how your service is implemented. But the above code will work as long as your url is correct.