# how to call comon web service for both ios and android in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

- > Iam new to Xamarin, how to call webservice for both ios and android
  >   with single code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

before you post a new question , search for existing ,

[consuming a php webservice in Xamarin PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552709/consuming-a-php-webservice-in-xamarin-pcl)

duplicated !

BTW you can use httpClient

```
//Use this class as a singleton in an IoC container
class MyAppClient
{
  readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

  public async Task<string> GetChuck()
  {
    return await _httpClient.Get("http://chucknorris.com");
  }
}

//Although "using" is good in general, don't do this
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
  return await _httpClient.Get("http://chucknorris.com");
}
```

*code example taken from http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/improving-http-performance-in-xamarin-applications*